# Computer is really messed up, need to know how to salvage ubuntu after hard reset during 14.10 installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I bought my Lenovo T520 back in 2011, and for a while I had no problems, but then I decided to install Windows 8, which was initially unsuccessful because I was using unofficial methods. I eventually managed it, although I am sure some of the files were missing or something like that.

Eventually I got curious about Ubuntu last year and gave it a try.

Now because (I think) of these files or drivers or whatnot missing, the update popup for 14.10 always would pop-up, and then ask for my password so it could go forward with the upgrade.

The upgrade was going fine, and I just locked my PC only to come back and being unable to do anything except look at the lock screen and wave my mouse around. I did a hard reset, and when I tried to go to Ubuntu from my GRUB menu,it gave me a weird message saying it was unable to mount my kernel.

The exact message is

```
unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

Even the recovery wouldn't work, so I went to a previous version of Ubuntu, which lost a lot of the configurations I made on Ubuntu recently, but all my files are there. The problem is it won't even try to connect to wifi, and it's very slow.

It won't even shut down, it just lets me log out.

So after almost a full year I'm back on Windows having decided it'd be best to just do a factory reset. Unfortunately Windows is saying I have missing files which I'll need to provide through recovery media, which I don't have. Same with refresh.

Is there anyway to do a factory reset through Ubuntu, or a way to fix whatever mistake I made by doing the hard reset? Please try to keep the explanations basic.

Comment: Boot a live 14.10 usb, if that works do a fresh install of 14.10, DO not format your root ( / ) directory. If 14.10 does not work, re-install 14.04 . Failed upgrades take a long time and a lot of effort to debug while a fresh install takes 20 min or so.

Answer (score 1):

From what i've heard from this post,it looks like you don't have any important files on your PC, and I assume you have backups.For this the best thing to do would to:

- Download Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from another computer
- Get a usb with about 2GB of space on it
- Make it bootable. [(Follow this guide if the computer is Windows)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
- Plug that in to the computer you are having issues with
- And then as the computer is starting up go to the boot menu and boot from the USB

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to reinstall Ubuntu. There is no other option. Follow Johnn's post above for information regarding this fix.

For future reference, don't lock your computer while rewriting data. The lock screen uses data that, if overwritten or deleted by something, will  hang and, more importantly, break your current platform.

Comment: Can you please expand on this answer a little?  Providing a step by step on how to do this would be ideal.  As it is at the moment, it may be better suited to be a comment, rather than an answer. :)

Comment: I realised that after I posted it, yet neglected to delete it. I don't like deleting my responses; it makes me feel like I'm hiding something. I'll expand on it.

Comment: Excellent!  If more people did that, it would make for a great database of potential fixes :)

Comment: Sadly, I couldn't expand on it. The second part of my response is something I feel the need to say. The first part is to make it into an answer.